# creating FaultException from wcf message

Tags: wcf

I have a wcf based system that uses IRequestChannel to send a raw WCF message over the channel. Although the service contracts are not known ahead of time, Fault contracts are known, so i know everytime there is a fault message, it should map to FaultException type.

Also we are using XmlSerializer  for serializers since DCS is very picky..

for example below

```
 var requestChannel = this.GetRequestChannel();
 using (requestChannel as IDisposable)
 {
       responseMessage = requestChannel.Request(requestMessage);
  }
  if (responseMessage.IsFault)
  {
        throw new ApplicationException("Fault");                
  }
```

Is there any way to create the generic fault exception instance from a message ?

Comment: What kind of fault exception would you like? Something other than `new FaultException()`?

Comment: I know that all fault messages are going to be of a certain type, lets say TDetail. So ideally i will like to create new FaultException<TDetail>(responseMessage);

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. Just `throw new FaultException<TDetail>(params);`

Comment: the code above is for the client, i want check if the response message is a Fault message, and if it is then create a fault exception from an instance of System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message class.

Comment: I've never tried this, but take a look at [MessageFault.CreateFault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344799.aspx)

Comment: this creates the non generic fault exception, looks like i might have to xml parse and create it myself, thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa345766.aspx looks interesting. Good luck. Few people need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the fault contract to your WCF operation contract:

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyFaultException))]
    string GetMessage();
}
```

Then when you have an error throw a fault exception:

```
MyFaultException theFault = new MyFaultException();
heFault.Reason = "Some Error Message";
throw new FaultException<MyFaultException>(theFault);
```

Comment: i dont have strongly typed contracts and i am just sending raw soap messages over wcf channels. Also i looking to create fault exception object from a wcf message.